# Working with HashMap it shown an error?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-mediaplayer

I am working with hash map and it shows an error:-

The method `add(HashMap<String,String>)` in the type `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(String)`

on this line:

```
songsList.add(fullpath);
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private Cursor musiccursor, videocursor; // projection for audio media files
String[] music = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DI‌​SPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE }; // projection for video media files
String[] video = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.DI‌​SPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
```

Comment: Please provide more code. It seems your `ArrayList` is meant to work with `HashMap` but instead you're giving it just a `String` for whatever reason.

Comment: private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 private Cursor musiccursor, videocursor;
 // projection for audio media files
  String[] music = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
  // projection for video media files
  String[] video = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is a generic.  It can be made to take any single type of variable, but it can only take the type it was declared as.  If looks like this was declared to take an ArrayList but you tried to add a String, or vice versa.

Comment: can you explain it with example please...??

Comment: Based on the code-  songsList.add must take a HashMap<String, String>.  fullPath is a string.  That won't work.  Did you want to just have the list of filenames?  Then use an ArrayList<String>.  If you actually wanted the full hashmap, you need to create a new hashmap, add fullpath to it, then add that hashmap to the ArrayList.